# Connect and switch multiple tables in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, entity

I have a database. It has a table ABC which receive record from another machine.
That table automatically create a new table with name ABC + the date the table is created when the table have about 3000 record.
Another table CDE will store the created table name's information.

My Windows Service will check the table ABC for new record and send it to another database. 
If the ABC table is at its limit, it will check table CDE to see if there's any other tables were created and go to that table and read record to send.

My question is "Does Entity Framework support connect to a table in database without 
mapping it into Entity Model ? If it does, how can we do that? "

Tks so much for any answer.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally do not think it possible because the whole idea of EF is the mapping database tables to entities, the model creates in another words if the table is not in the model you can not access it and you can not use in in your project,  since the model can't access  it does not know that the table actually exists on the database side it important to understand that in the application that uses the EF you are not querying db you are querying the EF classes and entity objects that have direct access to db so if the table is not on the model you may not use EF to do queering on it.  I would recommend  looking or writing some procedure that might dynamically update EF model if certain condition happens.

Comment: Tks, I understood :) So I have to find another solutions :)